# Reformatting a Haskell data constructor type program and reformatting it

Tags: haskell

We are given code in a SImpL.hs file that contains the following data constructors and types:

```
module SImpL where

data AExprT = ALit ValT -- a literal value (an Int)
              | AName NameT -- a variable name (a String)
              | Add AExprT AExprT -- one arithmetic expression added to another
              | Sub AExprT AExprT -- one arithmetic expression subtracted from another
              | Mult AExprT AExprT -- one arithmetic expression multiplied by another
              deriving (Show,Eq)

data BExprT = BLit Bool -- a literal value (True or False)
              | Eq AExprT AExprT -- an equality test between two arithmetic expressions
              | Less AExprT AExprT -- a "less than" test between two arithmetic expressions
              | Greater AExprT AExprT -- a "greater than" test between two arithmetic expressions
              | Not BExprT -- the negation of a boolean expression
              | And BExprT BExprT -- the "and" of two boolean expressions
              | Or BExprT BExprT -- the "or" of two boolean expressions
              deriving (Show,Eq)

type ValT = Integer

type NameT = String 

data StmtT = Assign NameT AExprT |   
             If BExprT StmtT StmtT | 
             While BExprT StmtT | 
             Seq [StmtT] -- If the list is empty, this is a statement that does nothing.    
             deriving (Show,Eq)  

If BExprT StmtT StmtT | 
             While BExprT StmtT | 
             Seq [StmtT] -- If the list is empty, this is a statement that does nothing.    
             deriving (Show,Eq)

type ProgT = StmtT 

type StateT = [(NameT, ValT)]
```

We are asked to do this task:

> Write a function called changeName which will take a SImpL program (a
>   value of type StmtT) and return a copy of this program with one of the
>   variable names changed.   This function should take three parameters:
>   two Strings and a SImpL program.  The strings represent variables
>   names.  Your function should return a copy of the program with all
>   instances of the first string replaced by the second string.  For
>   example, using a Java-like notation, if myProgram represents this
>   program:

```
x = 3
y = 14
z = 0
while (x < y)
   z = z + x*y
   x = x + 1
answer = z + y
```

> the result of changeName "x" "number" myProgram should be a
>   representation of this program:

```
number = 3
y = 14
z = 0
while (number  < y)
    z = z + number *y
    number = number  + 1
answer = z + y
```

> Your changeName function will need to have a case for each kind of
>   statement in the SImpL language and you will need a helper function to
>   change the names of variables inside expressions.

The pseudo-code I've worked up to is here below:

```
module Assignment3 where

import SImpL

changeName :: String -> String -> StmtT -> StmtT
changeName val1 val2 (Assign NameT AExprT) = ...
changeName val1 val2 (If BExprT StmtT StmtT) = ...
changeName val1 val2 (While BExprT StmtT) = ...
changeName val1 val2 (Seq [StmtT]) = ...
```

While I think I understand the basic gist of this, I am quite lost on the actual implementation of code.  For example if you run this code:

```
changeName "x" "num" testMyProgram...
```

where testMyProgram is simply

```
Assign "x" (ALit 3)
```

I do not know how to get Haskell to return a line of StmtT code, such as:

```
Assign "num" (ALit 3)
```

I'm pretty sure this is what the instructor wants from the instructions.

Comment: As a footnote...I'll keep looking at it nonstop and come back if I actually figure it out, but I've been staring at this for hours...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are required to make a function that deconstructs a term, and if one of its components needs replacing, construct a new term.

```
changeNameStmt x y (Assign a b) | x == a = Assign y (changeNameExpr x y b)
                                | otherwise = Assign a (changeNameExpr x y b)
...
```

Since `Expr` may also refer to variables, it is necessary to recurse into it and replace all occurences there.

```
changeNameExpr x y (Name n) | x == n = Name y
...
changeNameExpr x y (Add a b) = Add (changeNameExpr x y a) (changeNameExpr x y b)
```

Do this for all types that are involved in statements. You can define a class and make the types instances of it, if you want a polymorphic `changeName`.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand your code and the first deconstruction part, but I'm not sure what changeNameExpr x y b does.  Could you elaborate on why it's not sufficient to return Assign y b?

Comment: Ah, I think I understand now, thanks for the clarification.  Do we have to include Show and Eq cases in 'changeNameExpr' since they are derived?

Comment: `changeNameExpr` as a function does not rely on anything, since the types are all concrete and thus the only relevant `Eq` is present (for `String`). Don't forget to close the question, once satisfied.

Comment: Definitely, this solution helped greatly with understanding the project, thanks so much.